# Tableau hover over items behind floating text box

Tags: tableau-desktop

I made [this tableau map dashboard](https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/chris.wood7638/viz/happiness_16382020121870/Dashboard2?publish=yes). Each country has tooltip hover-over data but I can't hover over the countries behind the main text box.

Does anyone have a workaround for this, its seems pretty basic?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**In short, no.**

This has to do with the Item hierarchy for the dashboard.

Tableau 2021.3 is the most up to date version at the time of me posting this and there is no ability to have dual hierarchy as of yet.

[Documentation](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_organize_floatingandtiled.htm#:%7E:text=In%20Tableau%20Online%20and%20Tableau,floating%20objects%20in%20the%20hierarchy.)

Comment: thanks, I thought this was the case, I just hoped there was some workaround. i would have thought more people had this issue

Comment: I keep up with the software updates and changes with Tableau, and I will try to remember to let you know if this functionality changes. Please accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: You can explore the Map layers to properly point the markers in your map, all map layers allow hover tooltips